# Issue with Fedex Extension in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, ups-shipping

I am using Expresso Store in my sitewhich is built using ExpressionEngine.
I am also using Fedex Shipping and UPS Shipping extensions.

We have noticed an issue in our Fedex Shipping Extension.
When some of our customers order products, then the Fedex Shipping cost is calculated and displayed wrongly.

This is a very severe issue and we are receiving a lot of customer complaints due to this.

Our From Address:

Place - select 'Massachusetts' (US)
Zipcode - 02339

Shipping Address

Place -'nevada'
Zip-code - 89423

Following shipping methods are displayed in our site during order process:

```
 Local Pickup - $0.00
 Use Your Own Shipping Account - $0.00
 Contact Me to Discuss Shipping Options/Cost - $0.00
 Fedex Priority Overnight - $81.68
 Fedex Standard Overnight - $207.30
 FedEx 2 Day - $146.91
 FedEx Express Saver - $109.01
 FedEx Ground - $34.91
 UPS Domestic Ground - $35.08
 UPS Domestic 3 Day Select - $98.73
 UPS Domestic Second Day Air AM - $168.78
 UPS Domestic Second Day Air - $147.19
 UPS Domestic Next Day Air Saver - $208.57
 UPS Domestic Next Day Air Early AM - $249.86
 UPS Domestic Next Day Air - $216.56
```

My issue is with the 4th option - **Fedex Priority Overnight**. It's showing wrong value and that too lesser than the **Fedex Standard Overnight** option.
The actual cost for Fedex priority Overnight should have been around $200.

I have used the shipping calculator available in the Fedex website for this.
Ref : https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/standalone?method=goToPackageInfoPage

The shipping calculator was showing the cost as $233 for Fedex priority overnight, which should be the correct cost.

This clearly shows that there is something wrong with the Fedex Extension. It was wrongly displaying the value as $81, which is much lower than the actual value.

Options:

From : US
zip -code : 02339

To : US
zip-code : 89423

No. of packages - 1
Weight : 28lbs

Package type : Your packaging

Dimensions:

Length => 16
 Width => 8
 Height => 8
 Units => IN

Can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Are you sure the API credentials you are using are activated on Fedex's live servers and that the extension is not using test mode?

Comment: In the fedex extension, it's showing as test mode. When I change the option and verify my order process. The order process page is displaying Error - '
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Store\Exception\ShippingException' with message 'Authentication Failed''.

Comment: Jeremy, I obtained the fedex credentials as per the instructions in the following link: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html . I received an email with the following details - account number, meter no and password.   Can this be used for test as well as production environments.

Comment: I would imagine you need to contact Fedex about whether the account will work on both test and production environments. I would doubt the credentials work for both.

Comment: Sreenath, yes, check with Fedex with regard to your account details for both test and live modes. It's also worth asking them if they know any reason why there would be a difference with the options on your account for the Priority Overnight service. Let me know what they say about both and I'll carry on the conversation via the support ticket.

Comment: Ian, I am unable to contact the Fedex team. I have updated the details in the support ticket. Can you please check that

Comment: Hai Ian, The issue is fixed. If we use the test account credentials, the shipping costs will be displayed incorrectly. When I entered the correct API details, the shipping costs appeared correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments:

> The issue is fixed. If we use the test account credentials, the shipping costs will be displayed incorrectly. When I entered the production API details, the shipping costs appeared correctly.